# Composite Application Project POM Editor doesn't show dependencies of certain maven projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, wso2

In WSO2 Enterprise Integrator Tooling (aka Eclipse Mars.2 Release 4.5.2 with their plugins) I have 2 projects:

- Composite Application Project (CAP)
- Registry Resources Project (RRP)

The Design view of the *Composite Aplication Project POM Editor* doesn't show the resources of the RRP or others projects.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research I found that if You set a parent in the pom.xml of the *Registry Resources Project* and delete the tags *groupId* and *version* of the pom.xml, because it isn't neccesary because it's on the pom parent, then, the ***Composite Application Project POM Editor* doesn't show you the artifacts of this project**.

See it in action:

**In the Resources Registry Project:**

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>padre</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.example.recursos</groupId>
  <artifactId>recursos</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
```

or simply:

```
<groupId>com.example.recursos</groupId>
<artifactId>recursos</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

The Design View in the CAP project:
[image: Resources OK]

**In the Resources Registry Project:**

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>padre</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
 </parent>
 <artifactId>recursos</artifactId>
```

The Design View in the CAP project:
[image: Resources KO]

Maven even encourages you to avoid setting the groupId and version in a child project
[image]

Other **hint**:
When you open the *pom.xml* of a CAP in the *Composite Aplication Project POM Editor*, it allways set de *groupId* and *version* when you save it. Even although you have set the parent and delete both.